# PHP how to separate serial number (range of number)

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, pdo

I want to separate numbers, like a serial number, ex:
I've got `1-1000`,

- if I want to remove `1-100`, then I will get `101-1000`
- if I want to remove `901-1000`, then I will get `1-900`
- if I want to remove `101-200` then I will get `1-100` and `201-1000`
- and so on.

I just insert first number and last number, like 1 and 100.

The problem is, I am using MySQL to store data, this is my tables:

```
[items(id,name), serials(id,name), details(id,item_id,serial_id,first,last)][1]
```

I've a solution, but I think my solution is too long and isn't efficient for my code if I work with large data, this is my solution

```
public function checkSerialNum(array $data){
        $item_id = $data['item_id'];
        $serial_id = $data['serial_id'];
        $first = $data['first'];
        $last = $data['last'];
        
        if($first > $last) return false;
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE item_id = '$item_id' AND serial_id = '$serial_id'";
        $details = $this->db->run($sql)->fetchAll();
        $new_detail = [];
        foreach($details as $key => $detail){
            if($first == $detail->first && $last == $detail->last){ // 1 - 1000 -> 0 - 0
                $new_detail['item_id'][] = $item_id;
                $new_detail['serial_id'][] = $serial_id;
                $new_detail['first'][] = 0;
                $new_detail['last'][] = 0;
                $new_detail['old_id'][] = $detail->id;
            }elseif($first > $detail->first && $last == $detail->last){ // 901-1000 -> 1 - 900
                $new_detail['item_id'][] = $item_id;
                $new_detail['serial_id'][] = $serial_id;
                $new_detail['first'][] = $detail->first;
                $new_detail['last'][] = $first - 1;
                $new_detail['old_id'][] = $detail->id;
                
            }elseif($first == $detail->first && $last < $detail->last){ // 1 - 100 -> 101 - 1000
                $new_detail['item_id'][] = $item_id;
                $new_detail['serial_id'][] = $serial_id;
                $new_detail['first'][] = $last + 1;
                $new_detail['last'][] = $detail->last;
                $new_detail['old_id'][] = $detail->id;
            }elseif($first > $detail->first && $last < $detail->last){ //101-200 -> 1-100 & 201-1000
                $new_detail['item_id'][] = $item_id;
                $new_detail['serial_id'][] = $serial_id;
                $new_detail['first'][] = $detail->first;
                $new_detail['last'][] = $first - 1;
                $new_detail['old_id'][] = $detail->id;
                $new_detail['item_id'][] = $item_id;
                $new_detail['serial_id'][] = $serial_id;
                $new_detail['first'][] = $last + 1;
                $new_detail['last'][] = $detail->last;
            }
        }
        return $this->tidyArray($new_detail);
    }
    public function tidyArray($arr){
        $new_arr = [];
        foreach($arr as $k => $array){
            for($i=0;$i < count($array); $i++){
                $new_arr[$i][$k] = $array[$i];
            }
        }
        return $new_arr;
    }
    public function removeSerialNum(array $data){ //
        $new_details = $this->checkSerialNum($data);
        
        if(!$new_details) return false;
        
        $item_id = $data['item_id'];
        $serial_id = $data['serial_id'];
        
        foreach($new_details as $nd){
            if(isset($nd['old_id'])){
                $old_id = $nd['old_id'];
                $sql = "DELETE FROM details WHERE item_id = '$item_id' AND serial_id = '$serial_id' AND id = '$old_id'";
                $this->db->run($sql);
                unset($nd['old_id']);
            }
            $this->insertData('details',$nd);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `$data` is returning something like this

```
$data = [
   'first' => 1,
   'last' => 100,
   'item_id' => 1,
   'serial_id' => 1
];
```

The `function tidyArray()` is changing the format array from something like this:

```
////// it will return like this if I'm not breaking any range, like I've 821-900 and I just input 821-850
Array
(
    [item_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [serial_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [first] => Array
        (
            [0] => 821
        )
    [last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 850
        )
    [old_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )
)
/////but if I've 821-900 and input like 851-860, it will return like this
Array
(
    [item_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [serial_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [first] => Array
        (
            [0] => 821
            [1] => 861
        )

    [last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 850
            [1] => 900
        )

    [old_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

)
```

to something like this:

```
//////it will return like this if I'm not breaking any range, like I've 821-900 and I just input 821-850
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [serial_id] => 1
            [first] => 811
            [last] => 900
            [old_id] => 8
        )
)
/////but if I've 821-900 and input like 851-860, it will return like this, its like new range of data, I will explain old_id below..
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [serial_id] => 1
            [first] => 821
            [last] => 850
            [old_id] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [serial_id] => 1
            [first] => 861
            [last] => 900
        )

)
```

and the last is `function removeSerialNum()` this will delete the affected range of number, example I've `101-200, 301-900` in my database, then I want to remove `151-160`, so it will select using the affected row and that's `101-200` row then delete it and change with a new one, this is my data from the array above, this will explain what `old_id` use for:

```
"id"    "item_id"   "serial_id" "first" "last"
"3"      "1"             "1"    "101"   "150"
"4"      "1"             "1"    "161"   "200"
"5"      "1"             "1"    "301"   "350"
"7"      "1"             "1"    "701"   "800"
"9"      "1"             "1"    "802"   "810"
"10"     "1"             "1"    "821"   "900" ->the affected row
```

in case you wonder what is `function insertData()` looks like:

```
public function insertData($table,array $data){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
        $vals = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $val){
            $vals[] = "$key = '$val'";
        }
        $sql .= implode(',',$vals);
        return $this->db->run($sql);
    }
```

This solution is working for me and I just want to ask how can I get a same result but with less lines of code or in a smarter way.

Comment: Are you asking about a range of acceptable numbers? Because that would just be [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

Comment: not just like that, imagine it was a cheque, it was like sheets of paper with number, and you just took in the middle from 11-20, the you need to know what page remaining

Comment: or you can took the paper from begining to middle or middle to end or middle to middle

Comment: When I get this right you start with one row [1-1000] and every time you delete a range (for example 100-200) you want to update 1-1000 to 201-1000 and add a new row 1-99 correct?

Comment: @SirPilan, that's correct. sorry for late response, i think i solved this but i forgot to add an answer. Thank you for your response !